# fetch user details from log.nsf

Tags: c#, lotus-domino

hi 
My question is : In log.nsf , there are entries database accessed in last week. I am not able to find where these values resides as i am fetching these values from c# and using the domino.dll as reference.

kindly help me out to fetch the number of hits of database from any user in week. So that i can check that my database is active and how much being accessed by users.

Thanks in Advance

Ankit

Answer (score 0):

I think you use wrong approach. What I would do is to create a form with two fields - user name and access count and a view sorted by user name. Each time in the database open script search in the view for a document for he current user and update counter (+1). If no document found - create it for current user, set counter to one and save. If you also need dates, you can either add date field to the document and not use counter, just create a document every time your database has been opened and create a view categorized by date to see the usage. Number of documents per day would show you the usage. You can also add category per user if you like. I think using log.nsf for this purpose is not a good approach.